# Difference in token types

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

What is the terminology that is used to differentiate the difference between the accepting token and the tokens that are matched in the stream? As an example, here is what I mean:

```
Accepting Token
----------------
OPEN_PAREN: '(';
CLOSE_PAREN: ')';
PLUS: '+';
NUMBER: \d+;
```

```
Parsed Tokens
-------------------
# (2+(3))
[<OPEN_PAREN: '('>, <NUMBER: '2'>, <PLUS: '+'>, 
<OPEN_PAREN: '('>, <NUMBER: '3'>, <CLOSE_PAREN: ')'>, <CLOSE_PAREN: ')'>]
```

How are these two different items categorized? Currently I'm calling one `TOKENS` and the other `tokens` which is most confusing.

Comment: It depends on the textbook you use. But, generally speaking, the `token name` is the left-hand side symbol name of a rule. The job of the lexer is to read the input character stream and output a sequence of `token`, which is a tuple of `< token type, text >`. So, the symbol `OPEN_PAREN` is the `token name`. The `token type` would be an enum or integer value or the name itself, and `"("` is the token text. Note, tokens almost always include additional information, e.g. line, column, or index into the char buffer. You should read ISBN 9789332518667, 9780128154120, or 0521607647.

Comment: For reference: ISBNs = Dragon Book, Engineering a Compiler, and Modern Compiler Implementation in ML.

Comment: @kaby76 out of those three recommendations, which would you suggest as the first intro bookto tackle?

Comment: 9789332518667 is the classic book used by compiler developers.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for "the terminology", but I don't think there's a generally agreed answer to this question. (As such, the question may be inappropriate for Stack Overflow.)

Personally, I'd say that (e.g.)

- `NUMBER` is a lexical symbol,
- `NUMBER: \d+;` is a lexical production or lexical rule, and
- `<NUMBER: '2'> at line 1, column 2` is a token, or a lexical node, or an instance of the lexical production/rule.