# Writing the production rules of this finite state machine

Tags: parsing, grammar, state-machine, automata, finite-automata

Consider the following state diagram which accepts the alphabet `{0,1}` and accepts if the input string has two consecutive `0`'s or `1`'s:

[image]

`01001` --> Accept 
`101`   --> Reject

How would I write the production rules to show this? Is it just:

```
D -> C0 | B1 | D0 | D1
C -> A0 | B0
B -> A1 | C1
```

And if so, how would the terminals (0,1) be differentiated from the states (A,B,C) ? And should the state go before or after the input? That is, should it be `A1` or `1A` for example?

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answer because depending on which book you are reading, there might be slightly different definitions for those formalisms

Comment: @derpirscher I suppose "any" would be fine -- I just made up the above diagram, it's not from any book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar you suggest has no `A`: it's not a non-terminal because it has no production rules, and it's not a terminal because it's not present in the input. You could make that work by writing, for example, `C → 0 | B 0`, but a more general solution is to make `A` into a non-terminal using an ε-rule: `A → ε` and then
`C → A 0 | B 0`.

`B0` is misleading, because it looks like a single thing. But it's two grammatical symbols, a non-terminal (`B`) and a terminal `0`.

With those modifications, your grammar is fine. It's a left linear grammar; a right linear grammar can also be constructed from the FSA by considering in-transitions rather than out-transitions. In this version, the epsilon production corresponds to final states rather than initial states.

```
A → 1 B | 0 C
B → 0 C | 1 D
C → 1 B | 0 D
D → 0 D | 1 D | ε
```

If it's not obvious why the FSM corresponds to these two grammars, it's probably worth grabbing a pad of paper and constructing a derivation with each grammar for a few sample sentences. Compare the derivations you produce with the progress through the FSM for the same input.

Comment: thanks for this a few follow-up questions: (1) Why do you have `| ε` in the final `D` production? If there weren't a self-loop on `1,0` would the `ε` be optional? (2) Is there a standard way to differentiate between terminals and non-terminals -- for example `A -> '1' B` -- or is it not done in-line, and it's in the `V` (non-teminal) vs `Σ` (terminals)?

Comment: also as a side-note why did you delete the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74911725/difference-in-token-types? I found that answer, like all of your others, as great.

Comment: (1) because it's a final state. So if you reach it, you're there and you don't need another input. (2) yes, by definition. Although you can also do it implicitly: a non-terminal is on the LHS of some production and a terminal isn't. But that implicit definition only works if the grammar has been reduced to remove unreachable and non-productive non-terminals, so the formal model insists that the sets V and Σ be defined and that every grammar symbol be in exactly one of those sets.

Comment: ... i wasn't very happy with it so I wanted to rethink it a bit.